# Microsoft Graph API - Search for drive item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API and I am attempting to do a search, but everytime I do it says Results not found, even though I do know the files does exists.

Here is my URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ID of the folder I am searching in}/children/search(q='Document.pdf')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I didnt need the children in the URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ID of the folder I am searching in}/search(q='Document.pdf')
```